# preg_match not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match some link from some texts:

```
$reg = '#ok is it http://google.com/?s=us#';
$page = 'Well i think ! ok is it http://google.com/?s=us&ui=pl0 anyways it ok';

if(preg_match($reg,$page)){
  echo 'it work'; 
}else{
  echo 'not work';
}
```

Now the problem is , if i use `$reg = '#ok is it http://google.com/';` then its ok but when i use that one with "?=" it doesnt.

ok ! i understand there is some problem of syntax error is there any function or ready made function which automatically escape these special characters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax errors. You must escape all the special chars as '.', '?' and so on. Thus you have to replace the chars like this:

```
'.' -> '\.'
'?' -> '\?'
...
```

Anyway, the regex should be like this:

```
$reg = '#ok is it http:\/\/google\.com/\?s=us#';
```

Comment: well, the `.` will still match a literal `.` (and practically anything else), but the `?` certainly need to be escaped :D

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$reg = '#ok is it http://google.com/\?s=us#';
```

Answer (score 0):

Some characters are read as metacharacters by the REGEX engine, meaning that they have a special function within the engine's procedures, a few examples being **? (question mark), \ (slash), . (period), * (asterisk)** etcetera.

Just as with strings you would send with SQL that contains metacharacters, you will need to escape these characters manually by adding a trailing slash: **\.** When escaping the \ character, you might need to escape it three or four times like this: \\\ or \\\\.